# How to detect the OS of the device to share the app downloading link based on the OS?

Tags: java, android, ios, android-studio

I am working on an android app and I have provided a button to share the app. I want to share the link for downloading based on the OS of the device(mainly for iOS and android). I searched a lot, But could not find anything useful.

Comment: Can you please clarify? You're working on an Android app, how can you share it on iOS? And how do you want to share it?

Comment: I have the app link for play store and app store separately. When I share the link through social media then on the basis of the device OS, the link should be sent there on the media. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes there is. You can't share a link that refers to two separated results. So the idea is: you share a link and this link redirect to a page that is able to take a decision based on what is the user system/browser, and then redirects to the correct store (or a webpage if the user is not on a mobile). There are two possibilities to do that. You can implement it yourself with your own server, or you can use a service that do that for you (generally not for free). I don't have any particular example but you should be able to find something very easily by yourself.